# rewrite dynamic url after form submit

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My link is

```
search?c=category&s=product
```

I have already removed the .php with htaccess, everything is working apart from when a user searches, the first page will show the link above, I want to show the link as below:

```
search/category/product
```

I tried the below code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^product/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) product.php?id=$1&c=$2&name=$3

RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) search.php?c=$1&s=$2&page=$3

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+search\?c=([^&\ ]+)&s=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^ /search/%1/%2? [L,R]
```

What am I missing in the above?

Comment: Rule looks fine, what problem are you facing?

Comment: when they type in a query and click search the link is still showing as search?c=category&s=product

Comment: Where is this htaccess located and does it have other rules as well?

Comment: In the site directory, all other rewrites work, except the last two lines - updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have rules this way:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /site/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search\?c=([^&\s]+)&s=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ search/%1/%2? [L,R]

RewriteRule ^product/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ product.php?id=$1&c=$2&name=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ search.php?c=$1&s=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ search.php?c=$1&s=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: this fixed last two lines but added %20HTTP/1.1 to my search query

Comment: yeh this is correct but breaks the first page results because it needs page defined as 1

Comment: search/category/product/1 - works... search/category/product breaks

Comment: I had already tested that rule and it worked for me. You should create a new question rather than editing this one. Long comment sessions are not liked by moderators here.

Comment: new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31585926/dyanmic-url-not-rewriting-ht-access