# dyanmic url not rewriting ht access

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

All my rewrites are working apart from one.  When a user searches I want the URL to show correctly in the url bar.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /website/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search\?c=([^&\s]+)&s=([^&\s]+)&mincost=([^&\s]+)&maxcost=([^&\s]+)&sort_by=([^&\s]+)&colour=([^&\s]+) [NC]

RewriteRule ^search/%1/%2/%3/%4/%5/%6? [L,R]

RewriteRule ^product/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ product.php?id=$1&c=$2&name=$3&page=$4 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^product/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ product.php?id=$1&c=$2&name=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ search.php?c=$1&s=$2&mincost=$3&maxcost=$4&sort_by=$5&colour=$6&page=$7 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ search.php?c=$1&s=$2&mincost=$3&maxcost=$4&sort_by=$5&colour=$6 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

/website/search/category/all/100/500/low-to-high/any-colour

(works when entered into the url bar)

/website/search?c=category&s=all&mincost=100&maxcost=500&sort_by=low-to-high&colour=any-colour

(shows when using filter and submitting form) - I need this url to show as:

/website/search/category/all/100/500/low-to-high/any-colour

Comment: the search `form action="/website/search"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first `RewriteRule` is not correct. Replace it by:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search\?c=([^&\s]+)&s=([^&\s]+)&mincost=([^&\s]+)&maxcost=([^&\s]+)&sort_by=([^&\s]+)&colour=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ search/%1/%2/%3/%4/%5/%6? [L,R=302,NE]
```

Note space between `^` and `search`

Comment: if im on the search page already and search, the answer works, if im on home ( which also has a search form going to `/website/search` ) and search with same parameters it doesnt

Comment: Rule has nothing to do with your navigation. As long as **exact** `example.com/website/search?c=category&s=all&mincost=100&maxcost=500&sort_by=low-to-high&colour=any-colour` URL structure is coming to web server it will work.

Comment: ok ill have to check why thats happening, right now im running this on localhost, once uploaded to a domain I wont want the /website/ after the domain name, would I simply remove the `RewriteBase /website/` ?

Comment: Yes just replace that by `RewriteBase /`